# Indexing with Masked Arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a bit of code that attempts to find the contents of an array at indices specified by another, that may specify indices that are out of range of the former array.

```
input = np.arange(0, 5)
indices = np.array([0, 1, 2, 99])
```

What I want to do is this:
    print input[indices]
and get
    [0 1 2]

But this yields an exception (as expected):

```
IndexError: index 99 out of bounds 0<=index<5
```

So I thought I could use masked arrays to hide the out of bounds indices:

```
indices = np.ma.masked_greater_equal(indices, 5)
```

But still:

```
>print input[indices]
IndexError: index 99 out of bounds 0<=index<5
```

Even though:

```
>np.max(indices)
2
```

So I'm having to fill the masked array first, which is annoying, since I don't know what fill value I could use to not select any indices for those that are out of range:

> print input[np.ma.filled(indices, 0)]

```
[0 1 2 0]
```

So my question is: how can you use numpy efficiently to select indices safely from an array without overstepping the bounds of the input array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using masked arrays, you could remove the indices greater or equal to 5 like this:

```
print input[indices[indices<5]]
```

Edit: note that if you also wanted to discard negative indices, you could write:

```
print input[indices[(0 <= indices) & (indices < 5)]]
```

Comment: D'oh that works. I'm still curious about why we can't properly use masked arrays for indexing, but I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4):

It is a VERY BAD idea to index with masked arrays. There was a (very short) time with using MaskedArrays for indexing would have thrown an exception, but it was a bit too harsh...

In your test, you're filtering `indices` to find the  entries matching a condition. What should you do with the missing entries of your MaskedArray ? Is the condition False ? True ? Should you use a default ? It's up to you, the user, to decide what to do.

Using `indices.filled(0)` means that when an item of `indices` is masked (as in, undefined), you want to take the first index (0) as default. Probably not what you wanted.

Here, I would have simply used `input[indices.compressed()]` : the `compressed` method flattens your MaskedArray, keeping only the unmasked entries.

But as you realized, you probably didn't need MaskedArrays in the first place

Comment: `compressed` was what I was after, thanks. I had assumed that using masked arrays to index would effectively compress them first, which seems like a reasonable default. But I suppose that would probably require allocating a new array, which would make for an expensive default.