# Why does my array lose its mask after doing multidimensional indexing in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I wish to use a multidimensional MaskedArray as an index array:

Data:

```
In [149]: np.ma.arange(10, 60, 2)
Out[149]: 
masked_array(data = [10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54 56 58],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Indices:

```
In [140]: np.ma.array(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5), 
                      mask=np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5) % 3)
Out[140]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[0 -- -- 3 --]
 [-- 6 -- -- 9]
 [-- -- 12 -- --]
 [15 -- -- 18 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Desired Output:

```
In [151]: np.ma.arange(10, 60, 2)[np.ma.array(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5), mask=np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5) % 3)]
Out[151]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[10 -- -- 16 --]
 [-- 22 -- -- 28]
 [-- -- 34 -- --]
 [40 -- -- 46 --]],
             mask =
 False,
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Actual Output:

```
In [160]: np.ma.arange(10, 60, 2)[np.ma.array(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5), mask=np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5) % 3)]
Out[160]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[10 12 14 16 18]
 [20 22 24 26 28]
 [30 32 34 36 38]
 [40 42 44 46 48]],
             mask =
 False,
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Why does the resulting array lose its mask? According to an answer here: [Indexing with Masked Arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854665/indexing-with-masked-arrays-in-numpy), this method of indexing is very bad. Why?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new masked array that uses the mask of your indexing array? i.e. `new_masked_array = np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(10, 60, 2), indexing_array.mask`, where in your example, you'd previously define `indexing_array = np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(20).reshape((4,5)), np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))%3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like indexing with a masked array just ignores the mask.  Without digging much into the docs or code, I'd say the `numpy` array indexing has no special knowledge of the masked array subclass.  The array you get is just the normal `arange(20)` indexing.

But you could perform normal indexing, and 'copy' the mask:

```
In [13]: data=np.arange(10,60,2)

In [14]: mI = np.ma.array(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5),mask=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5) % 3)

...

In [16]: np.ma.array(data[mI], mask=mI.mask)
Out[16]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[10 -- -- 16 --]
 [-- 22 -- -- 28]
 [-- -- 34 -- --]
 [40 -- -- 46 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Do you really need to combine indexing and masking into one operation (and masking array).  This operation would work just as well if the mask were separate.

```
 I = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
 m = (np.arange(20).reshape(4,5) % 3)>0
 np.ma.array(data[I], mask=m)
```

If the masked index elements are invalid (e.g. out of range), you could fill them with something valid (followed by masking if needed):

```
data[mI.filled(fill_value=0)]
```

Have you seen in the numpy masked array docs an example of using a masked array to index another one?  Or are all the masked arrays 'data'?  It's possible that the designers never intended you to use masked indexes.

---

The masked array `.choose` works because it uses a method which has been subclassed for masked arrays.  Regular indexing probably converts the index to a regular array with something like:  `data[np.asarray(mI)]`.

---

The `__getitem__` method for the `MaskedArray` class starts:

```
    def __getitem__(self, indx):

        Return the item described by i, as a masked array.

        """
        # This test is useful, but we should keep things light...
#        if getmask(indx) is not nomask:
#            msg = "Masked arrays must be filled before they can be used as indices!"
#            raise IndexError(msg)
```

This is the method that is called when performing `[]` on a masked array.  Evidently the developer(s) considered formally blocking the use of a masked index, but decided it wasn't an important enough issue.  See `np.ma.core.py` file for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.choose.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.choose) method like this:

```
np.ma.array(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5), mask=np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5) % 3).
            choose(np.ma.arange(10, 60, 2))
```

which gives:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[10 -- -- 16 --]
 [-- 22 -- -- 28]
 [-- -- 34 -- --]
 [40 -- -- 46 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: This an interesting solution, but not generally applicable.  `choose` has a serious limitation:  `mI.choose(np.arange(0,32))` produces an error: `ValueError: Need between 2 and (32) array objects (inclusive).`.