# Slicing numpy array with arrays of indices, some of which are out of bounds

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using image data in the form of a numpy array with shape (1, 1, ny, nx) where nx and ny are typically ~20000. Currently, I extract the value at any position in the numpy array via:

```py
image = np.array([[[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                    [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
                    [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]]])
idx_y, idx_x = np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 0])
value_at_idx = image[0, 0, idx_y, idx_x]  ## == np.array([0.5, 0.7])
```

My problem occurs when the indices' arrays I pass in to the slicing contain indices which are out of bounds for the image's array, i.e.:

```py
idx_y, idx_x = np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 10])
value_at_idx = image[0, 0, idx_y, idx_x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 3
```

My goal is to return all image values (as a 1-D list/array) with a NaN for those requested indices which are out of range e.g. for the example above I would return `np.array([0.5, nan])`. Of course, currently I have the following non-numpy/inefficient code:

```py
mask = ((idx_ra > 0) & (idx_ra < nx)) &\
       ((idx_dec > 0) & (idx_dec < ny))

value_at_idx = []
for idx, i_ra in enumerate(idx_ra):
    if mask[idx]:
        value_at_idx.append(imdata[0, 0, idx_dec[idx], i_ra])
    else:
        value_at_idx.append(float('NaN'))
```

However, ideally I would like a numpy implementation for efficiency. I have only found posts similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854665/indexing-with-masked-arrays-in-numpy?rq=1), whereby out-of-range values are simply neglected. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this implentation, i don't know how efficient is this but give it a try.
First step is padding the array with `np.nan`

```
def nan_padding(image):
    image_y = image.shape[2]
    image_x = image.shape[3]

    h_nan = np.full(shape=(image_y,1) ,fill_value=np.nan)
    new_image1 = np.hstack((h_nan, image.reshape((image_y, image_x)), h_nan))

    v_nan = np.full(shape=(1,image_x+2) ,fill_value=np.nan)
    return np.vstack((v_nan, new_image1, v_nan)).reshape((1,1,image_y+2, image_x+2))
```

Second step is indexing using `np.take`:

```
def nan_indexing(image, idx_y, idx_x):
    new_indices = (idx_y + 1) * image.shape[2] + idx_x + 1
    return np.take(image, new_indices, mode='clip')
```

And now:

```
padded_image = nan_padding(image)
value_at_idx = nan_indexing(padded_image, idx_y, idx_x)
print(value_at_idx)
```

Input:

```
image = np.array([[[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                    [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
                    [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]]])
idx_y, idx_x = np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 0])
idx_y, idx_x = np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 10])
```

Output:

```
[0.5 0.7]
[0.5 nan]
```